# Cassandar DB : How to display output of describe tables in ascendant or descendant order?

Tags: cassandra, cql, cassandra-3.0, cqlsh

I am trying to execute this cql command to get list of tables in cassandra:

`cqlsh:myspace> describe tables;`

I am getting output like this:

```
site                    vehicle                  vehicle_brand         
vehicle_color           employee                 project  
...
...
```

I have many tables.

Is it possible to show list of tables displayed in ascendant or descendant order ?

If yes, how ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this by querying `system_schema.tables` table with CQL query like this:

```
select table_name from system_schema.tables 
   where keyspace_name = 'myspace' order by table_name desc;
```

Comment: That's answer my question. Thanks !

Comment: Can you help on this question also ? : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49881817/does-handling-nested-object-using-json-stringify-parse-cause-performance-issue